# How can we plot solids of revolution in python 3 (with matplotlib)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, calculus

I was a Scilab user, but I am changing to python (because I need Symbolic analys also), now I am new Python user, how to plot a solid of revolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib plots 3D meshes. With that you can plot a solid of revolution. You have several examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface). One such example is this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

If you want something more [direct](http://jamesgregson.blogspot.fr/2012/08/python-constructive-solid-geometry.html) you might want to try using [pycsg](https://github.com/timknip/pycsg), [pythonOCC](http://www.pythonocc.org/) framework or [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/fr/index.html).

The last resource is a bit outside Python. You can use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) (uses Python syntax) to do [Solids of Revolution](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/revolution_plot3d.html).